# Copy file from server to computer using scp

Tags: scp

[image]

I use the srcipt below to download a file but no file is downloaded.

```
scp /var/www/joomla/sql/rt_head_includes.php root@202.xx.xx.xx:D:\mydocument
```

What's wrong with the script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download a file from server to my d drive folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/954584/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-server-to-my-d-drive-folder)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this might work if your windows machine runs ssh server. Does it? If not, you might need to use something like winscp on that windows machine. Not sure if you can script winscp. Besides that, when dealing with windows paths you need to escape backslashes.

Comment: I have edit my question. I use the script but no file was downloaded. Is my script wrong?

Comment: Strange. Which ssh server are running on that windows machine? Does it by any chance have some configurations of where files are copied to, like root directory or something similar?