# How do I download a file from server to my d drive folder?

Tags: scp

[image]

How do I download a file from server to my D:\mydocument?

```
scp /var/www/joomla/sql/rt_head_includes.php root@202.xx.xx.xx:D:\mydocument
```

Comment: Is the local path wrong?

Comment: Does that `202.xx` server really run Windows? If it does, 1) which SSH server exactly does it run and 2) why does it have a "root" account?

Comment: If I copy file from server directory to server directory. It's work. Now I can't copy it from server directory to my computer directory. @grawity

Comment: Uh, what. Can you please try answering my questions, instead of just repeating what you already said

Comment: 202.xx. server running in linux. It is my website server. Root is the main admin. I want to copy file from server to my computer. @grawity

Comment: Your computer is running windows? Which Version?

Comment: Windows xp professional version 2002 service pack 3. @vembutech

Comment: What ssh server software is installed on the 202 system?

Answer (score 2):

Use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) tool. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"""` to scope the path as following command format:

```
scp <Source Pth> <USER>@<Dst IP>:"""<Target Pth>"""
```

For Example:

```
scp /pth/to/file.txt administrator@192.168.8.1:"""D:\pth\to\dir"""
```